# How do I use tagList() in a Shiny module?

Tags: r, shiny

The official [tutorial by RStudio](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) is a little unclear on how to actually use the tagList() function for creating a namespaced ID in Shiny modules. The [Shiny documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shiny/versions/0.14.2/topics/tag) does not help much either. What exactly am I supposed to put inside the tagList() function? Should I only wrap input arguments in a tagList(), like shown in all examples and video tutorials, or can I put other elements in there, such as a sidebarPanel()?

Comment: Could you reference the documentation and provide a code sample of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Description is now updated with a link to the documentation. My goal is to understand how to use the tagList() function properly when creating a Shiny module.

Comment: No one can give you an authoritative answer if R-Studio will not. Best is to try it out and see where it gets inserted. You can view html in  the R-Studio html preview function quite well, or open the browser and use the Chrome html debugger.

Comment: You could also ask on the Shiny discussion list in Google Groups if you wanted to get the attention of the code authors (with luck).

Comment: Thanks all for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Are the google groups of shiny still active ? How are they better than stack overflow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`tagList()` creates nothing but a simple list of tags. The definition is

```
> tagList
function (...) 
{
    lst <- list(...)
    class(lst) <- c("shiny.tag.list", "list")
    return(lst)
}
```

It's a simple list having a special class `shiny.tag.list`. You use it when you create a module, where the UI of the module needs to return a simple page, like a `fluidPage` etc. If you don't want to create an extra UI for the module, you just return a few UI elements wrapped inside `tagList` and take care of the UI outside of the module. For example:

```
library(shiny)

moduleUI <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    
    # return a list of tags
    tagList(h4("Select something"),
            selectInput(ns("select"), "Select here", choices=1:10))
  }

module <- function(input, output, session){}
  
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(wellPanel(moduleUI("module"))) # wrap everything that comes from the moduleUI in a wellPanel
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  callModule(module, "module")
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```